# jQuery function preventing form from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form

I'm working on this site: http://dev.rjlacount.com/treinaAronson-test

The problem I'm having is with the contact form (click the contact button on the top left to slide it open).

I'm using the following jQuery to cause the contact form to slide closed on esc key press or clicking outside of the open panel:

```
$(document).bind({
    keydown:function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27 ) {
            $("#panel").slideUp("3000");
            $("form#change-form-2")[0].reset();
            $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
                $('#fade').remove();  //fade them both out
            });
        }
    }, click: function(e) {
        $("#panel").slideUp("3000");
    }
});
$('#flip, #panel').bind('click', function(e){return false});
```

This works for what I need it to do, but is disabling the functionality of my submit button. It is also (although this is a more minor issue) causing the panel to close if I right-click anywhere. I'm pretty new to Javascript; would anybody mind helping me prevent this from disabling the functionality of the contact button?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the submit form to function normally, change "return false" to the following:  this will allow the form to function normally without allowing the event to bubble to the document.

```
$('#flip, #panel').bind('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Marlin, there you go fixing my problems again! Thanks a lot man - there's only one problem with this, the form functions normally now but the panel slides up after clicking the submit button. Do you know how I could exclude the submit button's ID from the code above to prevent this?

Comment: yeah,  i changed my response above from the ID solution to the stopPropagation() way.  Thought, that might be a problem.  Have you tried the solution above?

Comment: Yes! I was able to piece together the fix for the problem with the ID solution but this way is much better since it won't require a markup change. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `disabled` attribute of the `button`:

```
$("yourButtonSelector").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Thank you much for the response. This does stop the function from interfering with the Javascript but also disables the default submit button functionality, so the button does nothing. Is it possible to tell the button to behave normally?

Answer (score 0):

What if you bind the click just to the #content div?  Then there should not be any problems in your #contact div.